# PowerApp: Update field visibility based on another field answer

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am trying to update fields based on another field.

Ie if answer to Q1 = No,  Make questions Q1a, Q1b, Q1c, Q1d invisible.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are two basic ways of doing this:

In the "Visible" property of Q1a, Q1b etc. you insert the following formula:

```
If(Dropdown.Selected.Value = "yes", true, false)
```

Here I am assuming that Q1 is a dropdown with "yes" and "no" values. But it will work with other types of input controls as well.

The other way is that on the "OnChange" property of Q1 you insert this formular:

```
Set(varShowFields, If(Dropdown.Selected.Value = "yes", true, false))
```

This will update the "varShowFields" variable with either true or false depending if "yes" has been selected as an answer. In all the Q1a, b, c questions you then insert the following in the Visible property:

```
varShowFields
```

This great thing about this approach is that you only have to maintain any change in visibility logic one place when and if some requirements change.